# How to prove divergence for this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While proving divergence for this series:

$$\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^3}$$

I'm finding that while Symlabs says it diverges (and intuitively it should,) I can't prove it with either the comparison tests or the integral tests. The integral test actually gives me back a number indicating convergence, and the limit comparison tests are inconclusive.

Any ideas? Am I missing something basic?

(I should mention I'm doing practice problems for a Calculus II course so the only relevant tools in our toolkit are comparison tests and integral tests.)

Thank you!

Comment: It converges. You may invoke either the integral test or Cauchy condensation test to prove it.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1475376/505767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By integral test,

$$\int_5^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln^3 x} dx=^{x=e^t}=\int_{\ln 5}^\infty \frac{1}{t^3} dt<\infty$$

It is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{1}{x \log^3( x)} \,dx=-\frac{1}{2 \log ^2(x)}$$
$$\int_5^\infty \frac{1}{x \log^3 (x)} \,dx=\frac{1}{2 \log ^2(5)}=0.193029$$
While:
$$\sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log^3 (n)}= 0.219271$$